# How to clear animation in android?

Tags: java, android, animation

In my android app I am making a button shake using this code

```
public void FlashButton() {

    final Button button = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button_message));
    final Animation moveright = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.moveright);
    final Animation moveleft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.moveleft);
    final Animation moveright2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.moveright2);

    AnimationListener animation1Listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             button.startAnimation(moveleft);
        }
    };
    AnimationListener animation2Listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             button.startAnimation(moveright2);
        }
    };
    AnimationListener animation3Listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             button.startAnimation(moveright);
        }
    };

    moveright.setAnimationListener(animation1Listener);
    moveleft.setAnimationListener(animation2Listener);
    moveright2.setAnimationListener(animation3Listener);

    button.startAnimation(moveright);
}
```

This code sets three animations sequentially in a loop forever.

But how do I stop the animation, and make the button normal again?

I tried `.clearAnimation();` but it didn't work...

Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: onAnimationEnd() does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try cancelling the animations and see, something like

```
 moveright.cancel();
 moveright2.cancel();
 moveleft.cancel();
```

Or try reset as well

```
 moveright.reset();
```

similar for others

Answer (score 0):

If you can't solve the issue for whatever reason, I found that starting a new reset type animation can help:

```
.... <scale

android:duration="1"
android:fromXScale="1"
android:fromYScale="1"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toXScale="1"
android:toYScale="1" 
android:fillAfter="true"
```

/> ....